# Python : Array group by Sum value

Tags: python, numpy

Many topics exist to sum an array based on another array indexes but i couldn't find what i am looking for.

I have an array `[1,1,1,1,2,3,3,0,0,2,4]` and i would like to get indexes by which the sum until now is greater or equal to `4`. So I would get:

`[3, 5, 9, 10]` because:

```
Sum([1,1,1,1]) >= 4

Sum([2,3]) >= 4

Sum([3,0,0,2]) >= 4
```

I need the indexes of the element at which the sum value is fulfilled.

I could do it with a loop but i am looking for doing it efficiently with numpy or the like.

Comment: Could there be negative values?

Comment: What if the sum for the current group never reaches exactly 4, and the next item takes it over 4? Are the items guaranteed to be integers, or could there be floats?

Comment: Right, i updated the question, i was not clear enough, i need the slicing based on the first index where the cumsum passed the sum value i am looking for.

Comment: Think you should update with a more relevant sample. Maybe like : `[1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 4]`, so that the answers won't fall prey to the simplistic sample.

Comment: @Divakar : thx. I did already in my last update.

Comment: Thanks. Think it would be hard to vectorize. Look into `numba` if you are desperate for performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.where` in conjunction with `np.cumsum`:

```
import numpy as np

li = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,0,0,1,4]

print(np.where(np.cumsum(li) % 4 == 0))
# (array([ 3,  5,  9, 10], dtype=int32),)
```

The gotcha here of course is that it will also find indexes where the sum is 8, 12, 16, 20 etc.

Unfortunately I'm not sure there is way to "reset" `cumsum`, if there was you could do something like `np.where(np.cumsum(li) - 4 == 0)` (but currently it will only return 3).

However, you could slice the array every time `cumsum` reaches 4, but you didn't want to use loops.

Comment: What if it's `[1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 4]`? As an example of what PM 2Ring  commented about.

Answer (score 1):

```
array =[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,0,0,1,4]
print(np.where(np.cumsum(array)%4==0))
```

now, if you change your array then you can check whenever sum goes beyond 4 then u can take the last index and proceed further.